# How to integrate Watson Assistant chatbot with my own CRM?

Tags: python, django, dynamics-crm, ibm-cloud, watson-assistant

As the title suggests I have made a chatbot through IBM Watson Assistant and have implemented on my website. I have also made a separate CRM through Python and Django and I have created a separate Messages html where I want the chatbot messages to be recorded so that the sales representatives can follow up with potential customers.

Is there an easy way to do this? Can the messages be recorded in the CRM??

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate your chatbat (your assistant) in several ways. You probably have taken a look at the sections on [integrating with your website](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-deploy-web-chat) and [custom integrations](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-deploy-custom-app). A custom integration is probably what you need if you want to store the messages in your CRM. Basically, you would use the API to send messages to Watson Assistant and receive the responses. Your app would collect user input and display the responses. Both could be stored in your CRM.